# Ionic popover with React - How to make it sticky to the button

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

Following the Ionic documentation, I am trying to get the popover sticky to the button ([like on their own example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover)). 
Unfortunately I do not know how to achieve this... 
Thanks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IonPopover, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';

export const PopoverExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <IonPopover
        isOpen={showPopover}
        onDidDismiss={e => setShowPopover(false)}
      >
        <p>This is popover content</p>
      </IonPopover>
      <IonButton onClick={() => setShowPopover(true)}>Show Popover</IonButton>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You also need to include an event in the showPopover hook -

```
const [showPopover, setShowPopover] = useState<{open: boolean, event: Event | undefined}>({
  open: false,
  event: undefined,
});

<IonPopover
    isOpen={showPopover.open}
    event={showPopover.event}
    onDidDismiss={e => setShowPopover({open: false, event: undefined})}
>
   <p>This is popover content</p>
</IonPopover>
<IonButton onClick={(e) => setShowPopover({open: true, event: e.nativeEvent})}>Click</IonButton>
```

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Comment: Could you do me a favour and mark this as the answer if it helped you? Thanks!